# re-number observations in a large data frame

Tags: r, performance, naming, large-files

I'm dealing with a data frame with over 500,000 observations, and I'm dealing with code optimization for the first time.  I have a very simple problem that is just killing me on time, and was looking for a faster solution.

My data frame "d" has a column for the observation numbers that simply go from 1:nrow(d).  For reasons that are not important here, the observations need to be re-numbered in a specific way. I have another data frame, called "id", that has the wrong number for observation 1 in column 1, and the right number in column 2.  These columns are named "wrong" and "right", respectively.

The way I've tried to re-number is with a loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  d$obs[i] <- id$right[id$wrong==d$obs[i]]
}
```

Like I said, this is terribly slow.  Any ideas for a smarter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be faster:

```
 d$obs <- id$right[match(d$obs,id$wrong)]
```